# Python Aggregate column C based on A & B

Tags: python-2.7

I have some log files that I am trying to analyze. Using a little regex I have gotten the following structure:

**Month/Year, URL, Count**

`Sep 2016,/,100513
Sep 2016,/,68221
Oct 2016,/,536365
Oct 2016,/,362350
Oct 2016,/,89203
Nov 2016,/,526455
Nov 2016,/,351360
Nov 2016,/,88279
Dec 2016,/,538702
Dec 2016,/,156063
Dec 2016,/,89094
Jan 2017,/,535684
Jan 2017,/,105867
Jan 2017,/,87492
Feb 2017,/,483897
Feb 2017,/,80502
Feb 2017,/,47554
Mar 2017,/,434830
Mar 2017,/,72355
Mar 2017,/,43036`

It's several 100k lines long so I can't use Excel or Google Sheets so I am trying to aggregate the Count by both Month and URL in python. What is a good method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using pandas. Your example is a csv file so the following would work.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('x.csv', parse_dates=True)

print df.groupby(['Month/Year', 'URL']).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a solution without external dependencies (maybe a strict corporate environment):

```
months = {}
urls   = {}

with open ('./parsed-data.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
       # [Month, URL, Count]
       data = line.split(',')
       months[data[0]] = months.setdefault(data[0], 0) + int(data[2])
       urls[data[1]]   = urls.setdefault(data[1], 0) + int(data[2])

# Do whatever with months and urls here
```